# PHP to XML - Replace/Trim Special Character

Tags: php, mysql, xml

How do I replace `”` into `"` in my php code?

Current XML output (Partial)

```
<content type="html"><![CDATA[<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

<p style="text-align: justify;"><br style=”clear:both;”/>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

<p style="text-align: justify;"><br style=”clear:both;”/>Click <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">here</a> for more information.]]></content>
```

As you can see there is `”` wrapping `clear:both;` style. All I want is replace it to `"`.

My PHP Code (not working)

```
<content type="html"><![CDATA[<?php echo str_replace("\”","",$row["content"]); ?>]]></content>
```

PS: The `”` already inside database.
Update:

If you test on your server with

```
    <?php

    $data = "<a style=”clear:both;”></a>";

    echo str_replace('”','"',$data);

    ?>

Output : "clear:both;"
```

It will never work. 

But if you try with

```
    <?php

    $data = "”clear:both;”";

    echo str_replace('”','"',$data);

    ?>

Output : nothing
```

It's working! But I want it work within  tag....

Comment: Maybe you mean `str_replace("”","\"",$row["content"]);`?

Comment: you'd be better off fixing what's in the DB. why clean up garbage every time you query the DB, when you could clean up the DB **ONCE** and never have to clean up again?

Comment: I think `update table set column = replace(column, '”', '"');` would do it for you. Then fix up whereever these quotes come from.

Comment: @MarcB ... unless your database is sat underneath a CMS that uses a WYSIWYG editor that allows users to "Post from Word" .... *The horror ... the HORROR!*

Comment: @CD001: at least it's not adobe pagemill output.

Comment: Your code `$data = "<a style=”clear:both;”></a>"; echo str_replace('”','"',$data);` works perfectly for me, it outputs `<a style="clear:both;"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested, and the following is working fine for me:

```
<?php echo str_replace ( '”','"', $row["content"] ); ?>
```

I'm replacing ” with ".

**Edit:**
Replace the quotes in your source or if not possible, before you insert it to your database.

Comment: Tried, not working. Perhaps you try on within html tag instead of ”clear:both;” ?

Comment: I do update my post, please check the new update. Refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $value = '<p style="text-align: justify;"><br style=”clear:both;”/>Click <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">here</a> for more information.]]></content>';

    echo $value;
    echo str_replace("”","\"",$value)
?>
```

[image]

`str_replace ( "”","\"", $row["content"] );` In you're case.

Comment: Hi, it's not working.

<?php

$data = "<a style=”clear:both;”></a>";

echo str_replace('”','"',$data);

?>

but it work under if (testing environment)

<?php

$data = "”clear:both;”";

echo str_replace('”','"',$data);

?>